# Combining mupltiple update statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a scenario where I am updating about 40000 worker records in the below manner:

1. I have to first update workers who have a role-id of 1.
2. then the remaining with role-id of 2,0,3 only for the ones which did not get updated in the previous update.

My question: is there any way I can combine all the 4 into a single update statement?

My concern is that my production server is very powerful with multiple processors and might get deadlocked as I am updating the same table again and again. We have had this issue in other places where we had to replace a user defined function.

Here is the sample update script:

```
UPDATE A 
SET Start_Office = B.TX_LCTN,
    Start_Worker_ID = B.wrkr_id_prsn    
FROM #FinalRes A
INNER JOIN #StartData B ON A.ID_CASE = B.ID_CASE     
                        AND A.Case_Open_Date = B.Case_Open_Date
WHERE B.CD_ROLE = 1

UPDATE A 
SET Start_Office = B.TX_LCTN,
    Start_Worker_ID = B.wrkr_id_prsn
FROM #FinalRes A
INNER JOIN #StartData B ON A.ID_CASE = B.ID_CASE
                        AND A.Case_Open_Date = B.Case_Open_Date
WHERE A.Start_Worker_ID IS NULL
  AND B.CD_ROLE = 2

UPDATE A 
SET Start_Office = B.TX_LCTN,
    Start_Worker_ID = B.wrkr_id_prsn
FROM #FinalRes A
INNER JOIN #StartData B ON A.ID_CASE = B.ID_CASE
                        AND A.Case_Open_Date = B.Case_Open_Date
WHERE A.Start_Worker_ID IS NULL
  AND B.CD_ROLE = 0

UPDATE A 
SET Start_Office = B.TX_LCTN,
    Start_Worker_ID = B.wrkr_id_prsn
FROM #FinalRes A
INNER JOIN #StartData B ON A.ID_CASE = B.ID_CASE
                        AND A.Case_Open_Date = B.Case_Open_Date
WHERE A.Start_Worker_ID IS NULL
  AND B.CD_ROLE = 3
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, `apply` can help:

```
UPDATE fr
    SET Start_Office = sd.TX_LCTN,
        Start_Worker_ID = sd.wrkr_id_prsn    
    FROM #FinalRes fr APPLY
         (SELECT TOP 1 sd.*
          FROM #StartData sd
          WHERE sd.ID_CASE = fr.ID_CASE AND
                sd.Case_Open_Date = fr.Case_Open_Date
          ORDER BY sd.CD_ROLE 
         ) sd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - that helped.